Jprofiler object allocation time is empty, even when "Record object allocation times" is checked
I am trying to analyze a memory leak with jprofiler.
I have checked "Record object allocation times" in the settings when starting the profiling session.

But the object allocation times in the References view of the Heap walker are shown as n/a. Also, the Time view of the Heal walker is empty.


I have checked with both Instrumentation and Full profiling modes, but the issue is there in both modes.
What could be the reason for this?

I found the issue. Jprofiler only records allocation times when memory is recorded, so I had to record memory first (Live Memory -> Recorded Objects -> Start Recording)
